# iPhone - release crash when using a class attribute

Tags: iphone, attributes, crash, release

Simple question...

Why does this `release` crash my app when I click on a button that is on the overlayController view?

```
    OverlayViewController* overlayController = [[OverlayViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"Overlay"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayController.view;
    [overlayController release];
```

Said another way, how can the OverlayViewController methods be called outside of this viewDidLoad method?

Strange... I do not understand why my app is working :-)

Comment: What does your console say when the crash occurs? Have you tried "build & debug" instead of "build & run" to see the stack trace when the crash occurs? Have you added `NSLog(@"x");` lines between each line of code to see which line actually causes the crash?

Comment: @e.James : it's the release that make the thing crash, but I had mistaken the cause. See EDIT. Console says nothing

Comment: Cool. then my answer will actually fix it. See below! `:)`

Comment: To sum it up, you are creating and then releasing the `overlayController` object, so it does not stick around. By the time you click the button, that overlayController has been released. The button event will be sent to an undefined block of memory, and your app will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can answer the second question easily enough:

> How can the OverlayViewController methods be called outside of this viewDidLoad method?

Simply add a property to your viewController:

> **MyViewController.h:**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    OverlayViewController* overlayController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) OverlayViewController* overlayController;
@end
```

> **MyViewController.m:**

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize overlayController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    OverlayViewController* ovc = [[OverlayViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
    self.overlayController = ovc;
    [ovc release];
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayController.view;
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    [self.overlayController someMethod];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [overlayController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't the set method retain the view
>   attribute

Yes but it doesn't retain `overlayController` which will be happily deallocated after `[overlayController release]`.

To be able to call `overlayController` methods keep it in instance variable. You have to do this anyway to avoid crashes and/or leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the view of the overlayController to your property but release the whole controller afterwards. The setter does only retain if you've specified this like

```
@property(retain)NSArray * myArray;
```

Have a look at the property of cameraOverlayView if this really retains the view.